# Enumerate paragraphs and subparagraphs like sections but with letters

Tags: sectioning, numbering, paragraphs

I'm using pandoc and in my `template.tex` exists this code to make the paragraphs and subparagraphs to behave like sections.

```latex
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
```

This code generate number like this:

```
1. chapter

1.1 section

1.1.1 subsection

1.1.1.1 subsubsection

1.1.1.1.1 paragraph

1.1.1.1.1.1 subparagraph
```

How to change this code to enumerate with letter like this:

```
1. chapter

1.1 section

1.1.1 subsection

1.1.1.1 subsubsection

1.1.1.1.a paragraph

1.1.1.1.a.a subparagraph
```

Comment: I don't think that piece of code does anything, as `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` are both defined in the default document classes. The only thing you may have to do is add `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection.\alph{paragraph}}` and `\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\theparagraph.\alph{subparagraph}}`. If you're having more than 26 paragraphs or subparagraphs, then you need to considering using the [`alphalph` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) for higher-order alphabetic enumeration.

Answer (score 4):

Your code snippet seems completely unrelated as both `\paragraph`s and `\subparagraph`s are both defined under the default document classes.

The only thing you may want to add to your preamble is:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% Display enumeration up to \subparagraph (level 5)
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection.\alph{paragraph}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\theparagraph.\alph{subparagraph}}
```

If you have more than 26 paragraphs or subparagraphs, you need to consider using the [`alphalph` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) which allows for higher-order alphabetic enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the picture attached in the question:

[Limiting the width of the verbatim text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703244/limiting-the-width-of-the-verbatim-text)

The following packages & commands (in the preamble) will help enumerate the paragraphs and subparagraphs:

```
\usepackage{AlphAlph}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
% For capital letters
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection.\AlphAlph{\value{paragraph}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\theparagraph.
\AlphAlph{\value{subparagraph}}}
```

Comment: Contributions are very welcome, but answers should not be simple links. In this case, you've linked to a poor quality question which includes an image of code which wouldn't be compilable even if retyped. Moreover, the substance of this answer is already in Werner's. Please either delete or improve this answer.