# Limiting the width of the verbatim text

Tags: verbatim

Hello Stack Exchangers

I am trying to limit the width of the verbatim text and the 'line 5' is out of the margins of the page. The example is showed in the picture where the rest of the lines are contained within the margins (by breaking the lines) except 'line 5'.

Suggestions on limiting the width of the text by using any packages & commands will be appreciated. For typesetting the commands (to take a screenshot to be attached as a picture), metaverbatim is used.

Cheers!
[image: packages and commands]

Comment: Welcome! Please never post images of code and always post complete minimal examples people can compile. What's metaverbatim? I'm clueless.

Comment: Put a CR just before AlphaAlph{... in line 5.

Comment: Off-topic: I've never heard of a package called `AlphAlph`. I do know about the `alphalph` package, though.

Comment: [Package `listings`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides options `breaklines`, `breakatwhitespace`, `linewidth`, `breakindent` etc. to automatically break long lines. See section 4.3.9 of the current user manual for more information. Unfortunately you've not added a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), so I cannot show you, how to change it to use `listings` and the suggested options.

Comment: @cabohah, I have downloaded the `listings` package from CTAN.

Comment: The `listings` package's `.dtx` cannot be compiled. The error `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.228   \item definelanguage}
                             , \hyperpage{43}` is coming up; however, the directory has got the style file and the package can be used.

Comment: The `.ind` file is missing which, in `dtx`, is present and is mentioned in the `l.3683`. `listings.ind` was not present when the package is downloaded from CTAN.

Comment: @alphabounce_1228 You don't need to download the listings package from CTAN. `listings` is available in the package manager of all TeX distributions. With MiKTeX use the MiKTeX console to install it. With TeX Live  or MacTeX use `tlmgr install listings`. With TeX Live from a Linux distribution install the corresponding Linux package. BTW: There are already questions and answers about package installation.

Comment: @cabohah, the package has to be compiled. Otherwise, it will just be about using the features of the package without getting into the gist of the formation of the package. Just using the package (without its full compilation in the local directory) has never been a good suggestion to the TeX users and developers.

Comment: ??? IMHO you want to *use* the features of the package to automatically break the lines of the listing in the generated PDF. For *using* a package provided by the used TeX distribution, installing it using the package manager is always recommended. Or do you also compile TeX yourself and generate the formats manually??? In this case you should know how to generate a package from `ins` and `dtx` and how to generate manuals from source. If not, this would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objective correctly, you need to fix not just line 5 but line 6 as well. If this is correct, I would like to suggest that you replace

```
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection.\AlphAlph{\value{paragraph}}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\theparagraph.\AlphAlph{\value{subparagraph}}}
```

with

```
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection.%
    \AlphAlph{\value{paragraph}}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\theparagraph.%
    \AlphAlph{\value{subparagraph}}}
```

As I trust you know, the `%` ("percent") character is TeX's default comment character. If it's placed immediately after the last "normal" character in an input line (as is the case in the suggested fixes), TeX doesn't "see" the embedded EOL character and continues by reading in the contents of the next line (while ignoring any whitespace characters that may be there at the start of the continuation line). Thus, as far as TeX is concerned, there is no difference between the two ways of executing the `\renewcommand` directives shown above.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph} % is there a package called 'AlphAlph' ?
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection.%
   \AlphAlph{\value{paragraph}}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\theparagraph.%
   \AlphAlph{\value{subparagraph}}}

\begin{document}

 \section{Once}
 \subsection{upon}
 \subsubsection{a time,}
 
 \addtocounter{paragraph}{26} % just for this example
 \paragraph{there was}
 
 \addtocounter{subparagraph}{288}
 \subparagraph{a beautiful frog.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: AlphAlph is the same as 'alphalph'  & it is by mistake that they both have been taken as two different packages. It seems like the capitalization in the usage of the command related to including the package does not matter (as \usepackage{alphalph} & \usepackage{AlphAlph}) or the other possibility is that both of the packages exist.